# Is there any block cipher which is also a pseudo-random-permutation over the key

Tags: block-cipher, pseudo-random-permutation

As block ciphers are defined as a pseudo-random-permutation over the data (keyed with the key), I was wondering, if there are also constructions for which key and data can be switched and the cipher is a permutation over the key space for a fixed (data) input?

So the question is, if the output space of $E_k(a)$ for all possible $k$ covers the entire space of $\{0,1\}^n$

More formally:

$E_k$ is a block cipher with key size equal to block size: $\{ 0, 1 \}^n \times \{ 0, 1 \}^n \rightarrow \{ 0, 1 \}^n $

and $\exists a \forall k_1, k_2: E_{k_1}(a) = E_{k_2}(a) \Rightarrow k_1 = k_2$

Or more generally: with $f$ a function $\{ 0, 1 \}^n \rightarrow \{ 0, 1 \}^n$

$\forall k_1, k_2: E_{k_1}(f(k_1)) = E_{k_2}(f(k_2)) \Rightarrow k_1 = k_2$

Or is this even true for every block cipher?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the "more generally" since in the latter definition you are applying a function of the key. This now makes it related to circular security. Regarding the basic question, this is not true in general, and I don't know if it's possible to build such a construction. What I can say is that there is a construction where the pseudorandomness property holds if the key is random OR if the data is random. This notion is studied in the paper [Symmetric and Dual PRFs from Standard Assumptions: A Generic Validation of an HMAC Assumption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1198.pdf) by Mihir Bellare and Anna Lysyanskaya. This paper would be a good starting point for research.